# Timeout: WebException when trying to access/debug LocalHost of Azure Functions [Unity] [PlayFab]

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, timeout, system.net.webexception, playfab

I'm trying to debug Azure Function scripts locally, in conjunction with Unity, but getting Timeout errors every time.

I have a few things here, and I'm not sure which one is actually causing the problem... It might be a settings on Windows, as oppose to one of the softwares.

I'm building in Unity 2019.4, and and using PlayFab and it's ability to use Azure Functions. When I try to execute scripts from the Azure servers, it functions correctly. But when I try to run it with Local Debugging, I get `WebException: The request timed out System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` (See full error below).

**Here's what I'm doing to setup:**

- Set PlayFab to Local Debugging (via VS Code Extension)(and confirming the json file is made in the temp folder)
- Install Azure Functions Core Tools from [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing)
- Start Azure Functions debugging from VS Code (terminal output shows that the the localhost is running it correctly)

Timeout error references the correct address `http://localhost:7071/api/CloudScript/ExecuteFunction` as confirmed in the VS Code Terminal when the AzFunc debugging is started.

*When I clone the project to my MacBook Pro, everything runs smoothly in local debugging.*

So, because of this, I've tried checking to make sure ports aren't blocked via PowerShell: `netsh firewall show state`,and told Windows Defender to not block anything from Unity or Code. When I run `Netstat -ab` in PowerShell/CMD, I do get:

```
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7071           DESKTOP-COMPUTER:0      LISTENING
 [func.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           DESKTOP-COMPUTER:0      LISTENING
```

I don't know if this is a problem, or normal...

I don't even know what else to check for. This problem is beyond me. If anyone knows the solution, or can point me in right direction, I'd be very grateful!

---

*Below are the two errors from the Unity log whenever I execute an Azure Function script through PlayFab while local debugging:*

```
WebException: The request timed out
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () (at <14e3453b740b4bd690e8d4e5a013a715>:0)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabWebRequest.Post (PlayFab.Internal.CallRequestContainer reqContainer) (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabWebRequest.cs:319)
Rethrow as WebException: Timeout: WebException making http request to: http://localhost:7071/api/CloudScript/ExecuteFunction
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabWebRequest:Post(CallRequestContainer) (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabWebRequest.cs:332)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabWebRequest:WorkerThreadMainLoop() (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabWebRequest.cs:252)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart()
```

```
Timeout: WebException making http request to: http://localhost:7071/api/CloudScript/ExecuteFunction
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
DemoScript:onPlayFabError(PlayFabError) (at Assets/PlayFabPartySDK/Examples/DemoScript.cs:264)
PlayFab.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass30_0:<QueueRequestError>b__0() (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabWebRequest.cs:395)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabWebRequest:Update() (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabWebRequest.cs:480)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabHttp:Update() (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabHTTP.cs:364)
```

Comment: A small update: using Postman, I was able to connect to the VS Code debugger. So, I suspect the issue is probably with Unity or PlayFab SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, TLDR: The answer to the problem is that not everything was updated. So, update *everything* if you're experiencing the same problem.

More specifically in my case, the "Visual Studio Code Editor" asset in Unity's Package Manager.

I just wanted throw this out there in case anyone has a problem like this in the future. It may not be the same specific thing that needs upgrading, but search around for everything involved and make sure it's updated. Not just the big, obvious things (like Unity or your IDE). Thankfully for me in this case, the update was starting to cause other problems, and after much headbanging trying to solve those, I came across it.

Good luck, future fellow idiots!